# Python - Sentiment analysis receiving error : 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running a sentiment analysis on a csv file and I am receiving this error message. I have tried a few things to resolve it and have not been successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
def sentimentAFINN(text):
    words = pattern_split.split(text.lower())
    sentiments =  len(list(map(lambda word: afinn.get(word, 0), words)))
    if sentiments:
        sentiment = float(sum(sentiments))/math.sqrt(len(sentiments))

    else:
        sentiment = 0
    return sentiment

def sentimentDisplayValue(sentimentScore):
    if sentimentScore > 0.1:
        return "Positive" 
    elif sentimentScore < -0.1:
        return "Negative"
    else:
        return "Neutral"



totals = defaultdict(int)

for (index, row) in data.iterrows():
    text = row['comment']
    text_munged = munger(text)
    sentimentScore = sentimentAFINN(text_munged)
    sentimentDisplay = sentimentDisplayValue(sentimentScore)
    totals[sentimentDisplay] = totals[sentimentDisplay] + 1
    pt.add_row([text_munged, sentimentScore,  sentimentDisplay])

print (pt)
print (totals)
```

This is my error message:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-b20887003b41> in <module>
      4     text = row['LikelyToReferComment']
      5     text_munged = munger(text)
----> 6     sentimentScore = sentimentAFINN(text_munged)
      7     sentimentDisplay = sentimentDisplayValue(sentimentScore)
      8     totals[sentimentDisplay] = totals[sentimentDisplay] + 1

<ipython-input-72-f95f79f94b60> in sentimentAFINN(text)
     29     sentiments =  len(list(map(lambda word: afinn.get(word, 0), words)))
     30     if sentiments:
---> 31         sentiment = float(sum(sentiments))/math.sqrt(len(sentiments))
     32 
     33     else:

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Try removing the `len` on line 29...

Comment: Thank you Ed Ward but that didnt work :(

Comment: break all your statements that have more than one operation into separate lines, this will reveal the exact line that causes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sentiments` variable is an `int` since its the value returned by `len()`. You are trying to call `sum()` and `len()` on `sentiments`. Both `sum()` and `len()` expect an iterable datatype.

You can change your `sentimentAFINN()` like this

```py
def sentimentAFINN(text):
    words = pattern_split.split(text.lower())
    # save your list in sentiments
    sentiments =  list(map(lambda word: afinn.get(word, 0), words))
    # now you check length of sentiments and return accordingly
    return float(sum(sentiments))/math.sqrt(len(sentiments)) if len(sentiments) > 0 else 0
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you 1! This fixed it and I completely understand what the issue was.

Comment: Glad to hear i could help @AmandaMorrow ! Also it would be helpful for future readers who come across this post if you could accept the answer if it resolved your problem

Comment: Done! Thank you!